# Use of git commit to push to local repo

Tags: git, git-commit

I came to know that the 'git commit' command is to save the files in local repo. 
The local repo is our computer where we locally make changes. If so why do we need to use the command to save the changes in local? Please someone explain me.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to `git commit` so then you could `git push` to make your work available on your team's remote repository, it's **for working as a team**.
- But that seems not all. Everybody says that `git` is for collaboration, to "work as a team". But occasionally I created repositories locally and work by myself to save what I did. Imagine you want to find out what you did last month to make a feature A work, after making a ton of changes since then, how could it be possible without a git history. So second is you make commits to **save your changes as rational pieces of history to know what you were doing**.
- Another reason is to **"back up" what you're doing**. You've just made a feature A working, and after some extra effort adding feature B, the whole app is broken. If you've committed your changes after having done feature A, then you could easily roll back to "recent working" version of your repository to remake the app working again. Or even cooler, looking at the changes to find out what've added to lead the app broken, then fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Committing a file registers those changes to the repo - it stores the changes from the previous commit with your summary and allows you to rollback changes to that point. When you `git push` to a remote repository, it pushes *all* of the changes to the remote repo along with every commit. Someone else accessing that repo can then `git pull` to retrieve all of your commits, with the ability to rollback to any one of them, not just the most recent version of your files.

Answer (score 0):

git is a VCS (version control system). Local changes are not automatically added to the repo. You must add files to the staging area using git add  before you can commit changes.
Commits allow for history in git log and to revert changes. A commit essentially creates a snapshot of the changes to the files on the branch.
You generally wouldn't want to commit changes until you have working code. This keeps you from pushing bad code to the remote.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Where you locally make changes is ONE PART of the local repo.  When you commit, that copies them to a different part of the repo.  I'll come back to a more detailed "why" in a second...

Your local repo has three main storage areas:  The worktree (where you edit files with tools like text editors or an IDE) ; the staging area (sometimes called the index) ; and the database (made up mostly of refs, commits, and the objects that provide details about the commits)[1].

The *commit* is a snapshot of the project.  It's the basic unit of your project's history.  You can reload the code as it looked in any commit.  You can merge divergent sets of changes if they resulted in commits.  You can see what's changed since a previous commit.  All of these operations where you interact with the past versions of your project are possible only if you commit, because without commits your project has no history.

---

[1] In truth, the index and the database share some important features, so to call it three storage areas is a little fuzzy - but that seems to be the standard way of explaining it, and it is at least true that they are *functionally* three different things.